# Is a proof required for the Division Algorithm for polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

I understand that the Division Algorithm can be applied to polynomials. Namely, for polynomials, for any polynomials $f,g$, there exist polynomials $q,r$ such that $f = gq + r$, with $\deg(f) > \deg (g).$ What does a proof of this look like? Is it an assumption we can make that you can always divide two polynomials with a quotient and remainder? I remember we used a proof using the Well-Ordering principle to prove the Division  Algorithm for two integers, but how can this be done for polynomials? Is it a valid assumption to say that the quotient and remainder will exist?

For the record, I don't mean this with regards to $\gcd (f,g)$.

Comment: What you describe is called the Division Algorithm, not the Euclidean Algorithm. The Euclidean algorithm *uses* the division algorithm to find the greatest common divisor of two elements.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin. I will edit the post.

Comment: In fact, this holds over any field, or more generally: if $R$ is a commutative ring, $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $R[x]$ whose leading coefficient is a unit, and $g(x)$ is any polynomial in $R[x]$, then there exists polynomials $q(x),r(x)\in R[x]$ such that $g(x) = f(x)q(x) + r(x)$, and $r(x)=0$ or $\deg(r)\lt \deg(f)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you need is to be able to divide any coefficient by the leading coefficient of the divisor.

Explicitly, let $f(x) = a_nx^n+\cdots + a_1x + a_0$ be a polynomial with coefficients in some (commutative) ring, and assume that $a_n$ is a unit; that essentially means that you can “divide by $a_n$”. For example, for polynomials with integer coefficients, you would need the leading coefficient to be either $1$ or $-1$.

We prove that for every polynomial $g(x)$ (with coefficients in the same ring) there exist polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $g(x) = q(x)f(x) + r(x)$, with $r(x)=0$ or $\deg(r)\lt \deg(f)$. The polynomial $r(x)$ is the “remainder”, and the polynomial $q(x)$ is the “quotient”. We prove this by induction on $\deg(g)$.

If $g=0$, then we can take $q(x)=r(x) = 0$. Assume the result holds for any polynomial of degree strictly smaller than $k$, and that $\deg(g)=k$. Write
$$g(x) = b_kx^k+\cdots + b_1x + b_0.$$
Think long division. If $k\lt n=\deg(f)$, we let $q(x)=0$ and $r(x)=g(x)$.

If $k\geq n$, then think Long Division. Look at $q_1(x)=\frac{b_k}{a_n}x^{k-n}$. This makes sense, because we said we can divide by $a_n$, and because $k-n\geq 0$. Note that the leading term of $q_1(x)f(x)$ is exactly $b_kx^k$. Therefore, $g(x) - q_1(x)f(x)$ is either $0$ or of degree strictly smaller than $k$. Either way, by induction we know that there exist a polynomial $q_2(x)$ and a remainder $r(x)$ with $r(x)=0$ or $\deg(r)\lt\deg(f)$, and
$$g(x)-q_1(x)f(x) = q_2(x)f(x) + r(x).$$
But then we have
$$g(x) = q_1(x)f(x)+q_2(x)f(x) + r(x) = (q_1(x)+q_2(x))f(x)+r(x),$$
with $r(x)=0$ or $\deg(r)\lt\deg(f)$. Letting $q(x)=q_1(x)+q_2(x)$ we are done.

Note that the Well-ordering principle for the nonnegative integers is essentially equivalent to induction.

Once you have this it is straightforward to go further and prove uniqueness, again under the assumption that you can always divide by $a_n$.

When the coefficients are in a field (like $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{C}$) this always holds, which means you can always do division with remainder for one polynomial divided by a nonzero polynomial.

Comment: I've seen papers that say things along the lines of "WOP iff Induction". Can you be more precise and explain a bit more on that?

Comment: @Luna145: That is well outside the scope of this question. I posted a proof (that contains a gap) in [sci.math many years ago](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/ntcZ4rkTItk/m/xvXAihyoRI0J). I think I’ve posted one here, but I can’t find it. See also this [related math.overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37944/induction-vs-strong-induction). Or you can post it as a question if you can’t find it already addressed here.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

The Euclidean algorithm can be proven to work in vast generality. The key part here is that you can use the fact that naturals are well ordered by looking at the *degree* of your remainder. The remainder's degree always strictly decreases, and so your process must terminate after finitely many steps, since each term you get a remainder with smaller and smaller degree and so eventually the remainder is constant and you're done.

Generally, Euclid's algorithm works as long as you can associate a positive integer called the norm to each nonzero element of your number system and perform some 'division' that reduces this norm.

Comment: So if we prove the Euclidean Algorithm for the set of integers, is it able to be proved that it also works for polynomials? Or is there a proof of the Euclidean Algorithm for general sets with these properties? Where can I find a proof of this more "general" Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: The most general version of the Euclidean algorithm is that it holds in all Euclidean domains. The proof is standard and in most textbooks. **But you will learn nothing if you read it.** Someone showed you how to prove the Euclidean algorithm in Z already. Prove it yourself in general using the ideas laid out above, and you will learn much more than any book could teach you.

Comment: It’s the Division Algorithm, not the Euclidean Algorithm. The latter uses the former.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I will attempt to prove this on my own.